# problema com porta de acesso no node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

estou tentando aprender sobre angular2,  e estou me deparando com este problema.
quando eu digito : " live-server" me aparece este erro abaixo:

```
live-server
Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Tento digitar o comando para mudar a porta  :node-inspector --web-port=8099 e me aparece a mensagem a seguir:

```
node-inspector --web-port=8099
'node-inspector' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
```

Como faço para corrigir isso ?

Answer (score 1):

Muitas das vezes este erro ocorre por que a variável `PATH` foi instalada no AppData em vez de ser no local correto.

Talvez seu pacote foi instalado localmente e binário,e não na variável `PATH`.

Tente rodar `/node_modules/node-inspector/bin/inspector.js` no seu diretório do projeto.

Adicione `"C:\Program Files\nodejs"`(ambiente do sistema) como sua variável `PATH` do node.js.

Ou também pode ter sido erro durante a própria instalação do node.js por questão de permissão.

Neste caso,digite o seguinte código,para instalar com permissão o node.js inspector :

```
sudo npm install -g node-inspector
```

Lhe aconselho a dar uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636055/how-to-modify-the-path-variable-definitely-through-the-command-line-in-windows) sobre como modificar as variáveis no `PATH`.